# overlapping pattern matching in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

A beginner's question. In the code:

```
$a = 'aaagggaaa';

(@b) = ($a =~ /(a.+)(g.+)/);

print "$b[0]\n";
```

Why is `$b[0]` equal to **`aaagg`** and not **`aaa`**? In other words - why second group - `(g.+)` - matches only from last `g` ?

Comment: If you want to see Perl regex engine in action, try the `rxrx` utility from [Regexp::Debugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Debugger) module. It's very cool and educative.

Answer (score 3):

Because the first `.+` is "greedy", which means that it will try to match as many characters as possible.
If you want to turn out this "greedy" behaviour, you may replace `.+` by `.+?`, so `/(a.+?)(g.+)/` will return ( 'aaa', 'gggaaa').

Maybe, you've wanted to write `/(a+)(g+)/` (only 'a's in first group, and 'g's in second one).

Answer (score 1):

Perl regular expressions normally match the longest string possible.

In your code it matches with the last `g` and returns the output **aaagg**. If you want to get the output as **aaa**, then you need to use the non-greedy behavior. Use this code:

```
$a = 'aaagggaaa';
(@b) = ($a =~ /(a.+?)(g.+)/);
print "$b[0]\n";
```

It will output:

```
aaa
```

Clearly, the use of the `question mark` makes the match **ungreedy**.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression you wrote:

```
($a =~ /(a.+)(g.+)/);
```

catchs the `"a"` and any word as it can, finishing **in one `"g"`** followed by more characters. So the first `(a.+)` just matches `"aaagg"` until the match of the second part of your regular expression: `(g.+)` => `"gaaa"`

The `@b` array receives the two matches `"aaagg"` and `"gaaa"`. So, `$b[0]` just prints `"aaagg"`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first `.+` is causing the `g` to be matched as far to the right as possible.
To show you what is really happening I modified your code to output more illustrative [debug](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#%27debug%27-mode) information.

```
$ perl -Mre=debug -e'q[aaagggaaa] =~ /a.+[g ]/'
```

```
Compiling REx "a.+[g ]"
Final program:
   1: EXACT <a> (3)
   3: PLUS (5)
   4:   REG_ANY (0)
   5: ANYOF[ g][] (16)
  16: END (0)
anchored "a" at 0 (checking anchored) minlen 3
```

```
Guessing start of match in sv for REx "a.+[g ]" against "aaagggaaa"
Found anchored substr "a" at offset 0...
Guessed: match at offset 0
Matching REx "a.+[g ]" against "aaagggaaa"
   0 <> <aaagggaaa>          |  1:EXACT <a>(3)
   1 <a> <aagggaaa>          |  3:PLUS(5)
                                  REG_ANY can match 8 times out of 2147483647...
   9 <aaagggaaa> <>          |  5:  ANYOF[ g][](16)
                                    failed...
   8 <aaagggaa> <a>          |  5:  ANYOF[ g][](16)
                                    failed...
   7 <aaaggga> <aa>          |  5:  ANYOF[ g][](16)
                                    failed...
   6 <aaaggg> <aaa>          |  5:  ANYOF[ g][](16)
                                    failed...
   5 <aaagg> <gaaa>          |  5:  ANYOF[ g][](16)
   6 <aaaggg> <aaa>          | 16:  END(0)
Match successful!
Freeing REx: "a.+[g ]"
```

Notice that the first `.+` is capturing everything it can to start out with.
Then it has to backtrack until the `g` can be matched.

---

What you probably want is one of:

```
/( a+     )( g+  )/x;
/( a.+?   )( g.+ )/x;
/( a+     )( g.+ )/x;
/( a[^g]+ )( g.+ )/x;
/( a[^g]+ )( g+  )/x;
# etc.
```

Without more information from you, it is impossible to know what regex you want is.

Really regular expressions are a language in their own right, that is more complicated than the rest of Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a regex expression is greedy. You can turn it off using `?` character:

```
$a = 'aaagggaaa';
my @b = ($a =~ /(a.+)(g.+)/);
my @c = ($a =~ /(a.+?)(g.+)/);
print "@b\n";
print "@c\n";
```

Output:

```
aaagg gaaa
aaa gggaaa
```

But I'm not sure this is what You want! What about `abagggbb`? You need `aba`?